# Confused about the variables in RobotC?

Tags: robotc

I'm trying to program advanced functions in [RobotC](http://www.robotc.net/wiki/VEX2_Functions_Motors_and_Servos#motorType) but I'm not too sure I'm doing it right. I want to specify the motor port I'm using, but I assigned names to all the motors. Funny thing though, they don't exactly work the same as regular variables.

For instance, motor[port7]'s alternate name is light_blue.

```
#pragma config(Motor,  port7,           light_blue,    tmotorVex393, openLoop)
```

I'm not really sure if these are new variables, or just specifications.  Anyway, here is the variable's signature:

```
int motor[tMotor motor]
```

My code plans on doing something similar to this:

```
void testThing (Motor motorName)
{
  motorName = someValue;
}

testThing(light_blue);
```

But with the int/motor hybrid variable/unidentified I'm not sure how well that would work out. Or at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #pragma is more like a #define in terms of names, as opposed to a variable declaration.

Your code is very close; something like this would work fine;

```
#pragma config(Motor,  motorA,          light_blue,    tmotorNXT, PIDControl, encoder)

void testThing (tMotor  motor_name)
{
    motor[motor_name] = 20;   // set power to 20
}

task main()
{
    testThing(light_blue);
}
```

The actual type of a tmotor is an enum (and used like an int) and the definition can be found in RobotCintrinsics.c included with the product.

for exmaple;

```
#if (1)

  // the actual 'enum' values for 'tMotor' are automatically defined by the ROBOTC compiler. Each platform
  // and circuit board type has its own set of "enum names" and it was becoming too hard to manage them in
  // this file. So they are automatically configured by the compiler which has better utilities for managing
  // differences between platform types.

  typedef enum tMotor;

#else

    // The old definitions are temporarily maintained here as well until the new implementation is confirmed
  // to be working well!

  #if defined(NXT) || defined(TETRIX)

        typedef enum
        {
          motorA = 0,
          motorB = 1,
          motorC = 2,
          mtr_S1_C1_1 =  3,

    ... etc
```

If i was to look at your code, and accept its functionality as literal then the following would work;

```
#pragma config(Motor,  motorA,          light_blue,    tmotorNXT, PIDControl, encoder)
#pragma config(Motor,  motorB,          light_green,   tmotorNXT, PIDControl, encoder)

void testThing (tMotor&  motor_name)
{
    tmotor_name = light_green;
}

task main()
{
    tmotor motor_to_use = light_blue;
    testThing(motor_to_use);
    motor[motor_to_use] = 20; // will actually move light_green since testThing function changed its value
}
```

It's hard to guess what it is you are trying to actually do

Comment: Exactly, but I actually need to know the compatibility between word types, since tMotor is not a type, just a specification.

Comment: Nevermind, tMotor can be used as a variable specification. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where you're confused, and you're correct in noticing that the motor variables are a little different than regular variables.

The `#pragma config( )` is actually doing a *lot* of heavy lifting for you because it is a "[preprocessor directive](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)".  In other words, there is a hidden step — preprocessing — between the code you wrote and the code that the compiler sees.  The preprocessor is why you have access to the `motor[ ]` array (which you didn't need to declare before using), and why assigning a value to a `motor` causes your real-world motors to move (which does not happen when assigning to a "normal" variable).  The code generated by the preprocessor is saving you from writing a lot of setup code yourself, but it is also making some normal-looking variables do some unexpected things.

In your case, this is the motor config line that you wrote:

```
#pragma config(Motor,  port7,           light_blue,    tmotorVex393, openLoop)
```

This tells the preprocessor to generate some code that does the following:

1. Declare a variable of type `tMotor` and store it in `motor[light_blue]`
2. Set the port of `motor[light_blue]` to `port7`
3. Add a function that gets called when you assign a value to `motor[light_blue]`, which converts that value directly to a power-level signal understood by Vex 393 (and outputs this signal on `port7`).  In other words, use *open loop* control instead of PID control.
4. (Other things not relevant to this question)

So, `light_blue` is not an "alternate name" for `motor[port7]`, and in fact **neither of those names are correct**.  The correct way to refer to this motor in code is `motor[light_blue]`.   In other words, `light_blue` is an index into the `motor[ ]` array.

The [code that Spiked3 posted](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/753/350) would be the proper way to set up your function:

```
#pragma config(Motor,  motorA,          light_blue,    tmotorNXT, PIDControl, encoder)

void testThing (tMotor  motor_name)
{
    motor[motor_name] = 20;   // set power to 20
}

task main()
{
    testThing(light_blue);
}
```

Comment: Nice guess :)  Actually motor[] is more like an array of output ports. It is a built-in variable, and not generated because of the #pragma. light_blue is just an index. RobotC has some weird compiling in that motor[idx] is the same as motor(idx) - and it can and does get confusing because samples are written both ways. It is a 'C' like language, but not a pure 'C' by any means.

Comment: I agree that `motor` is a built-in variable, but I'm saying that it originates from the preprocessor -- not specifically as a result of the `#pragma config( )`.  Most likely it's part of some header file that's pulled into every project as part of an automatic `#include`.

Comment: yes, that is correct. specifically
    intrinsic word property(motor, propertyMotorPower, kNumbOfTotalMotors, tMotor);
equates the RobotC variable to a firmware variable. I just wanted to make the point that there is not really any additionally generated code from the preprocessor in this case.